# Installing workloads to Visual Studio after initial installation

Tags: visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio Community a while ago and only installed the bare minimum workloads I needed (to save space). I now want to play around with Unity a bit but didn't install the mobile & gaming workloads.

Is there a way I can install those workloads from my currently installed IDE?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Click the Windows button to open the "start" menu of your windows, and search for "Visual Studio Installer". There, you should see a menu that allows you to add additional workloads.

Comment: Pretty elementary, thank you. Just have to click on the modify button when VS Installer loads

Comment: Yes, knowing to hit the modify button helps.